Typescript doesn't see the buttons
This is typescript and html code for a "simple" program that I am working on. Comments are in my native language, but they don't tell much. I can't get my buttons to work. I tried a lot of things, but nothing seems to work.
Also I know that ngOnInit is activated at the start of the website, but I put saveNumbers( ) in there just so that I could see the progress of the program life.
Also, my input numbers never change.
Component's template:
<body>

  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>

  <div id="grid">
    <table>
      <tr *ngFor="let row of tableData">
        <td *ngFor="let cell of row">
          {{ cell }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div id="stevila">
    <p>Števila od 7 do 45</p>
    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="vrednost" min="7" max="45" name="stevilo1" required>
    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="vrednost2" name="stevilo2" min="7" max="45" required>
    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="vrednost3" name="stevilo3" min="7" max="45" required>
    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="vrednost4" name="stevilo4" min="7" max="45" required>
    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="vrednost5" name="stevilo5" min="7" max="45" required>
    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="vrednost6" name="stevilo6" min="7" max="45" required>
    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="vrednost7" name="stevilo7" min="7" max="45" required>
    <button (click)="saveNumbers()">Kombiniraj</button>

    <input #inputElement type="text" />
    <button (click)="getValue()">Get Value</button>

  </div>

  <div id="grid2">
    <table class="zbiralnik" *ngIf="stevila.length">
      <tr *ngFor="let row of stevila" class="zbiralnik">
        <td *ngFor="let cell of row" class="zbiralnik">
          {{ cell }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</body>

Component:
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { clearInterval } from 'node:timers';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('inputElement') inputElement!: ElementRef;

  title = 'Loto srečka';

  tableData: number[][] = []; //ime tabele in kaj shranjuje

  //generiranje cifer

  vrednost: any = 10;
  vrednost2: any = 7;
  vrednost3: any = 14;
  vrednost4: any = 17;
  vrednost5: any = 19;
  vrednost6: any = 23;
  vrednost7: any = 26;

  stevila: string[][] = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.tableData = this.tabela(); //shrani rezultat tabele
    this.stevila = this.saveNumbers(); //izvede celotno funkcijo
  }

  saveNumbers() {
    console.log('Button clicked!');
    const tabelica: number[] = [this.vrednost,
    this.vrednost2,
    this.vrednost3,
    this.vrednost4,
    this.vrednost5,
    this.vrednost6,
    this.vrednost7].filter(val => val !== null) as number[];

    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      this.stevila[i] = Array(7).fill('');

      for (let j = 0; j < this.stevila[i].length; j++) {
        this.stevila[i][j] = tabelica[i] + " " + tabelica[j];

        if (i == j || i == j + 1 || i == j + 2 || i == j + 3 || i == j + 4 || i == j + 5 || i == j + 6)
          this.stevila[i][j] = "";


      }//druga

    }//prva

    return this.stevila;
  }

  tabela(): number[][] {
    const arr: number[][] = Array.from({ length: 5 }, () => Array(5));
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        let stevilo = Math.floor(Math.random() * (45 - 7 + 1)) + 7;

        while (arr[i].includes(stevilo)) { // pregleduje ali je v tej vrsti tabele že to število, če je true, potem naredi novo, ce ke false gre dalje
          stevilo = Math.floor(Math.random() * (45 - 7 + 1)) + 7;
        }

        arr[i][j] = stevilo;
        console.log(arr[i][j]);
      }

    }
    return arr;
  }

  getValue() {
    console.log(this.inputElement.nativeElement.value); // This will print the input value
  }
}


Do you see a console entry with 'button clicked' ?

Will be very helpful if you could attach a non-working demo on stackblitz. Meanwhile, do you see your console.log outputs from your code in the browser?

No. i see the output of the console in the VS terminal

I noticed you have this on your ngOnInit function:
this.stevila = this.saveNumbers();
But saveNumbers() returns the same instance. The change detection will not notice the change because the array object is still the same. In that function, create a new array, push the data and then return the variable

I had this in the NgOnInit just so I could see the array, when I was making the for loops. Also how would you do that?
